# Azure Functions OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle with certifi

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, certifi

I have several Azure Functions running each day but every once in a while, the Function App suddenly starts to raise OSErrors related to the TLS CA certificate bundle from certifi. The exact error is: `OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`.

About 1-3 minutes after this error occurred for the first time it suddenly disappears again, and the Functions run as normal.

I did find the following issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1805. However, this issue was unfortunately closed automatically. So, my question is if there are any permanent solutions to solve this bug while running a Function App since most questions on stackoverflow seem to be about code running on a local machine?

I have several Azure Functions running each day but every once in a while, the Function App suddenly starts to raise OSErrors related to the TLS CA certificate bundle from certifi. The exact error is: `Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`.

About 1-3 minutes after this error occurred for the first time it suddenly disappears again, and the Functions run as normal.

I did find the following issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1805. However, this issue was unfortunately closed automatically. So, my question is if there are any permanent solutions to solve this bug while running a Function App since most questions on stackoverflow seem to be about code running on a local machine?

Comment: Have you found a solution already? Running into the same problem but have not found a solution so far...

Comment: unfortunately I have not yet found a solution...